# Function satisfies the differential equation at a point but it's not included in the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm reading Ordinary differential equations by Tenenbaum and Pollard and there was this problem in exercise 3 of first chapter, the question is:
Is the function defined by y=x^2 a solution of the differential equation xy'=2y and if yes, then what is the common interval for which the solution and the differential equation make sense?
Now the answer given in the book was it is a solution for all x excluding 0, but my point is, both the function and its derivative exist and are clearly defined at x=0 and they satisfy the differential equation at x=0, since at x=0, y=0 and y'=0 so why isn't it a solution at x=0?

Comment: I don't understand the books answer either. We would have that $y=x^2$ satisfies this ODE for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

> [B]ut... both the function and its derivative exist and are clearly defined at $x=0\ldots.$

On the contrary, the derivative as defined by the differential equation does not exist at said point. That is, the equation $$xy'=2y$$ defines $y'$ for any $x,$ except for when $x=0.$ At that point, the equation tells us nothing about the derivative of $y.$

Thus, it is true that $y=x^2$ satisfies the equation at all points where the equation defines a derivative, namely, all points $x\ne 0.$

Comment: But the derivative of the function when seen independently will be y'=2x which is defined for all x including x=0, the derivative of the function is defined and satisfies the equation this way at x=0

Comment: @Rick No. The equation $$xy'=2y$$ is what we presumably want to solve. If you want to divide both sides by $x$ to solve for $y',$ that only makes sense so long as $x$ does not vanish. Another way to see this is that if you set $x=0,$ the equation becomes $0=2y,$ which is no longer a differential equation. In other words, if $x$ vanishes, the only solution is the zero function. No other solution exists for $x=0.$ We say $x=0$ is a singular point.

Answer (score 0):

the general solution is y=c*x^2
 for y(0)=0 you will find c=0 so y=0and this is the only solution through (0,0)
the limit of x^2 for x to 0 is also 0 but it is not a solution for y(0)=0
trula